# Create columns based on sequent row values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing about 300 000 rows with a structure like this:

```
name    Jack
gender  M
year    1993
country USA
city    Odessa
name    John
gender  M
year    1992
name    Sam
country Canada
city    Toronto
```

Is there a possibility to make dataframe looks like this using Pandas?

```
name    gender  year    country city
Jack    M       1993    USA     Odessa
John    M       1992        
Sam                     Canada  Toronto
```

Row with "name" is always there, but others could be absent. I try to use iterrows with no success.

Comment: don't you already have a data frame (with 300, 000 rows)?

Comment: Yes, I have. And it came as it is.

Comment: I don't understand: is your input a pandas data frame with two columns?

Comment: Yes! It has only two columns. What I need, is to go sequentially row by row and make columns based on unique values in column1 and fill columns with the appropriate value from column2.
Actually, it is a csv-file.

Comment: so, have you tried doing that? i mean building your final data frame sequentially with a for loop?

Comment: I'm some kind of newbie in Python and Pandas. I tried for a couple of hours, and I didn't get how to use for loop with Pandas.

Comment: name, gender and etc.. is it dataframe indices  of it's first column?

Comment: Indicies - yes, sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [17]:
g = np.cumsum(df.iloc[: , 0] == 'name')

In [15]:
df.groupby(g).apply(lambda x : pd.DataFrame(x.set_index([0]).T , columns=['name' , 'gender' , 'year' , 'country' , 'city']) )
Out[15]:
        name    gender  year   country  city
0                       
1   1   Jack    M      1993    USA      Odessa
2   1   John    M      1992    NaN      NaN
3   1   Sam    NaN      NaN    Canada   Toronto
```

Comment: Thank you very much fo your answer!
First line works like a charm, but the second one returns few errors. "# ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates" and others.

Comment: which version of `pandas` are you using and what kind of errors did you get ?

Comment: 0.16.2 version.

Full text of error is a quite long, so I put in the txt file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ktrd05cqy1g27wq/error-python.txt?dl=0

Comment: what is your first column name , the one that contains `name , gender , etc ,....` ? try to replace `x.set_index([0]).T` with `x.set_index(['column_name']).T`

Comment: Works brilliantly, thank you!
Your solution is so elegant, it stimulates me to learn deeper in groupby and apply methods.

Comment: Unfortunately, in real database, some values in types column could repeat for 2 or 3 times (i.e. 'name', 'gender',''city', 'year','city', 'name',...) after one name and it causes errors.

Comment: yeah sure this will cause error , but if you have 2 `city` column before `name` column appears in your frame , how your result should look like , it seems to me it's meaningless

Comment: Actually one person could be related to 1 or 2 or 3 cities and countries. So, may be the solution is columns named city1, city2 etc.